# How to Convert a CSV to a SQL Table WITHOUT 'Bulk Insert'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv, insert

I have a requirement to insert a CSV file into SQL, but am not permitted to use the Bulk Insert function...

The CSV file contains thousands of lines, each of which contain 3 fields I.e

John, Smith, 23

And I would like to pass this into a SQL table (MSSQL2008) WITHOUT calling the 'Bulk Insert' function. The table would be the same structure as the CSV I.e it would contain 3 columns and a row for each line in the CSV.

Does anyone know if this is at all possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `BULK INSERT` prohibited?

Comment: Also, look at the `Import Data` tool in SSMS. It can read from CSV files.

Comment: Wahat are your stack constraints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319895/upload-csv-files-using-sql-server-openrowset-function

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split3] (
@String nvarchar(MAX),
@SepColumn nvarchar(1),
@SepRow nvarchar(1)
)
RETURNS @T TABLE (
col1 nvarchar(50)
,col2 nvarchar(50)
,col3 nvarchar(50)
)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ParseXML xml

SET @String = LTRIM(RTRIM(@String))

--Remove last row separator from string
IF RIGHT(@String, 1) = @SepRow
    SET @String = LEFT(@String, LEN(@String)-1);

    SELECT @ParseXML = CONVERT(XML,'<r><c>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,@SepColumn,'</c><c>'),@SepRow,'</c></r><r><c>') + '</c></r>')

    INSERT @T
    SELECT
        NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('./c[1]','nvarchar(50)'))),'')
        ,NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('./c[2]','nvarchar(50)'))),'')
        ,NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('./c[3]','nvarchar(50)'))),'')
    FROM @ParseXML.nodes('//r') T(c);

 RETURN

 END
 GO
```

Example
`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split3] (N'John,Smith,23;Tom,Peter,6;', ',', ';')`